# UnsatisifedLinkedError : Could not locate stub library in jar file

Tags: java, ffi, jnr

I am trying to use this [jnr-jffi](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi) library. It appears to have a dependency on [jffi](https://github.com/jnr/jffi) so I have also built that and included in my libs folder.

My code to load the native code is as follows:

```
MATH_LIB = LibraryLoader.create(MathLib.class).load("math");

MATH_LIB.Multiply(1, 2);
```

And I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not locate stub library in jar file.  Tried [jni/Darwin/libjffi-1.2.dylib, /jni/Darwin/libjffi-1.2.dylib]
```

For what it's worth, I did include a folder `jni` that appears to contain a bunch of native libraries for various platforms.

How I can proceed to load my native code using this library.

Please note that I have tried adding various paths when launching my project and also adding the libraries to various locations on my machine, with no success.

That would mean I need to figure out how to debug further into this? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I'm sorry guys. Just seeing these comments now. I think I did fix it, but can't remember how.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) when using JNR. Maven will automatically resolve all the needed dependencies.

You can just add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.jnr</groupId>
     <artifactId>jnr-ffi</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Or find a more up-to-date version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jnr/jnr-ffi).

Comment: I tried adding this to the pom and packing it with the final jar. But it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need the platform specific version of the file: libjffi-1.2.dylib
Refer to [this](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1889) issue & try to find a relevant jar for your platform version which would contain the above library file.